# Get all bot commands discord.py

Tags: python, discord.py

I'm making a help command using discord.py rewrite and I need a way to iterate over all the commands I already have inside the bot, is there a way to do like bot.get_all_commands?

```
for command in bot.get_all_commands:
    print(command)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This worked for me

```
commands = bot.get_my_commands()
for command in commands:
    print(command)
```

Comment: [A code-only answer is not high quality](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/392712/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers). While this code may be useful, you can improve it by saying why it works, how it works, when it should be used, and what its limitations are. Please [edit] your answer to include explanation and link to relevant documentation.

Answer (score 2):

[`bot.commands`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html#discord.ext.commands.Bot.commands) returns all commands as [command objects](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html#discord.ext.commands.Command) in a [set](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html#discord.ext.commands.Command).

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`bot.all_commands`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html#discord.ext.commands.Bot.commands) to return all commands & aliases that you used before, See more in [discord.ext.command](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html#bots) .

Answer (score 0):

With version 2.0.0 and above, to get all commands we also need to get the new app command as well. Use the `bot.walk_commands()` method instead of `bot.commands` to get those under a group.

I've done it with this function:

```py
def get_all_commands(bot):
    return [
        *bot.walk_commands(),
        *bot.tree.walk_commands()
    ]
```